# cx_OracleTools CopyData.py - using without a PK constraint?

Tags: database, oracle, copying

I'm attempiting to use cx_OracleTool's CopyData.py script to copy data between two tables on separate Oracle schemas/instances:

http://cx-oracletools.sourceforge.net/cx_OracleTools.html

When I run it against my tables, I get the error:

```
No primary or unique constraint found on table.
```

I don't know much about Oracle, to be honest, but from what I can tell the tables don't seem to have any PK constraint or anything like that defined.

The merits of this aside, I think it's simply been setup that way for expediency, and it's unlikely to change anytime nearterm.

Is there any way to get copyData.py to run in this scenario without a PK constraint?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that CopyData checks to see if the row exists in the destination table, and it can't do that without a unique key.

If it is acceptable to insert all rows and not update changed ones, use the  --no-check-exists option. According to the code this will bypass the primary key check.

Otherwise, use the --key-columns=COLS option to manually specify the columns to be used as the unique key. This will also bypass the primary key check.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, yes, that works great =). I didn't realise that it used PK to check for existing records - that makes sense. Now, I just have to figure out how to run CopyData directly from another Python - it's not particularly OO or even function based, so I think that might take some mucking around. I'd rather not call subprocess just to run another Python script.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not geared towards programmatic usage: everything is inline and there aren't even any functions(!). Unless you feel like spending some serious effort rewriting the script, subprocess is probably your best approach.